# Why can't I use FragmentSupportManager inside a FragmentsStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, fragmentmanager

In the android documentation on FragmentStatePagerAdapter it is explained that the adapter can be set up like this:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance();
    }
}
```

I would like to use this, however, I would also like to manage the Fragments that were added with a FragmentManager. How can I do this? My approach is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(MyFragment.newInstance(), MyFragment.TAG).commit();
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.TAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before downvoting, can you just leave a short comment, please. Else I won't be able to clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this?

You write your own `PagerAdapter` implementation from scratch. `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will do their own fragment transactions, colliding with yours.

Comment: how should this custom pageradapter look like? Do you know the basic setup?

Comment: @user2426316: You might start by forking one of those two, as they are open source.

Comment: @user2426316: Here is the `v13` version of `FragmentPagerAdapter`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java The other ones are available at similar URLs.